# In Nifi how do we deleteMongo before putMongo (flowFile coming from ConvertRecord)

Tags: apache-nifi

I have gone through several posts but am not able to delete ALL records before putMongo.
My Flow is:

(1) "InvokeHttp"

(2) "ConvertRecord" (converts csv to Json)

(3) "ReplaceText" :-
Replacement Value : {}   (To Delete ALL records)
Replace Strategy : Always Replace
Evaluation Mode: Entire Text

(4) "deleteMongo"

(5) "putMongo"

But my question is : How do I make the Flowfile content of "ConvertRecord" available to putMongo

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to delete All collections before reloading.
The flow looks like:
InvokeHttp -> convertRecord -> putFile (saves Json data in a file) -> replaceText -> deleteMongo -> fetchFile -> PutMongoRecord